# How to use two where clauses with like operator in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am using **like** operator two times in different **where** clauses. If I try one **where** clause, It works fine, but with both. It doesn't work.

Here is my code.

```
$products = Product::where(['is_live'=>'N'])->where(['is_active'=>'Y'])->where(['is_deleted'=>'N']);
$products->where('payment_mode', 'like', '%Credit/Debit Card%');
        $products->where('payment_mode', 'like', '%Cash%');
$products = $products->get();
```

Please help.

Comment: ` It doesn't work.` what does it mean? Are you getting any error? Do you know that using multiple where would result in `AND` condition. So your query would result in `payment_mode like  '%Credit/Debit Card%' and payment_mode like  '%Cash%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be use `orWhere`

```
$products = Product::where(['is_live'=>'N'])
    ->where(['is_active'=>'Y'])
    ->where(['is_deleted'=>'N']) 
    ->where(function($query) {
        $query->where('payment_mode', 'like', '%Credit/Debit Card%')
              ->orwhere('payment_mode', 'like', '%Cash%');
    });
```

or you can use this

```
Product::where([
    'is_live'=>'N',
    'is_active'=>'Y',
    'is_deleted'=>'N'
])->where(function ($query) {
    $query
        ->where('payment_mode', 'like', '%Credit/Debit Card%')
        ->orwhere('payment_mode', 'like', '%Cash%');
})->get();
```

Comment: This query searching records where these both **Credit/Debit Card** and **Cash** keywords exists. Not those where only **Credit/Debit Card** or **cash** exists. I want all those records where these keywords exists whether single **cash** or **Credit/Debit Card** is there.

Comment: OK. Thanks. Your edited Code is works. But when these keywords **Credit/Debit Card** and **Cash** comes from foreach loop. @Davit